# What is the proper way to use inheritance when combined with factory method?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Given that I have 3 classes `Asset`, `AssetA`, `AssetB` what is the proper way to structure inheritance when using the factory method?

Here is how I would like to use these classes:

- `Asset.new(data)` should deterministically create either `AssetA` or `AssetB` depending on some flag present in `data`
- `Asset` should also act as a super class in a sense that it's methods should also be present in `AssetA` and `AssetB`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a base Asset class and have AssetA and AssetB inherit from it. The factory class should be a separate class - AssetFactory - with just one single responsibility - it should create new Asset object based on some conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Are you confusing simple factory with Factory Method?

A simple factory is a class (e.g., AssetFactory) that creates instances of the Asset hierarchy (e.g., AssetA or AssetB).

[image: Simple Factory]

Factory Method (Gang of Four) has two hierarchies, one of factories and products. I'm not sure how your problem relates to this.

[image: Factory method]